# How to properly test pcollection length when unit testing Apache Beam

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-beam

I am wondering which is the best way to test check the lenght of the output produced by a beam pipeline.

I have some testcode like this:

```py
test_data = [
    {'kind': 'storage#object', 'name': 'file1.doc', 'contentType': 'application/octet-stream', 'bucket': 'bucket123' },
    {'kind': 'storage#object', 'name': 'file2.pdf', 'contentType': 'application/pdf','bucket': 'bucket234'},
    {'kind': 'storage#object', 'name': 'file3.msg', 'contentType': 'message/rfc822', 'bucket': 'bucket345'}
]

with TestPipeline() as p:
   output = (p 
             | beam.Create(test_data)
             | beam.ParDo(DoFn_To_Test()).with_outputs('ok','error')
   )
```

I want to test sure that all elements in the test_data list go to 'output.ok'.
I think way to do it is to count them like this:

```py
with TestPipeline() as p:
   output = (p 
             | beam.Create(testdata) 
             | beam.ParDo(DoFn_To_Test()).with_outputs('ok','error')
   )

   okay_count = (output.ok | beam.Map(lambda x: ('dummy_key',x)) 
                 | beam.GroupByKey()  # This gets ('dumm_key',[element1,element2....])
                 | beam.Map(lambda x: len(x[1]) )  # Drop the key and get the lengh of the list
   )

   # And finally check^H^H^H^H^H^H assert the count is correct:
   assert_that(okay_count, equal_to([len(test_data)])
```

This works; but I don't feel this is the best way to do it, and I am sure there are more ways to do it.

### Best option (by now)

This is the best option suggested up to date: using beam.combiners.Count.Globally()

```py
with TestPipeline() as p:
   output = (p 
             | beam.Create(testdata) 
             | beam.ParDo(DoFn_To_Test()).with_outputs('ok','error')
   )

   okay_count = output | beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
   assert_that(okay_count, equal_to([len(test_data)])
```

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to use `Count.Globally()` https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/count/

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? The size of the output?

Comment: @AlexChermenin that does the trick! Thanks

Comment: @R.Esteves - yes, that's it. I just need to test that all X elements with some properties fo to the specific pcoll and I have the same number in and out (because some part of the transform emits more than one record)

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: beam.combiners.Count.Globally() also works and is easier to read! Any other idea?

Comment: Looking to your code again now, this is actually the best option. I suggest that you add it as an answer

Comment: @AlexChermenin: Can you please add the best option as an answer? The idea was yours :-) - just copy & paste from my updated question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question in the the question. Writing it here as an answer:

```
with TestPipeline() as p:
   output = (p 
             | beam.Create(testdata) 
             | beam.ParDo(DoFn_To_Test()).with_outputs('ok','error')
   )

   okay_count = output | beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
   assert_that(okay_count, equal_to([len(test_data)])
```

Comment: In this case, `okay_count` is just a PCollection you can't compare it with an integer